# does Firefox send url load http request only once? can it be made to resend it automatically if no response?

Tags: firefox, http

when browsing with Firefox on intermittent connection I notice that I often open a bunch of tabs with new pages and these tabs just keep on "connecting" / spinning while doing nothing forever. But if I manually go to the tab, do Stop and ENTER in address bar, i.e. resend the request, then it will correctly load the page.

Am I correct in thinking that this is because the http request is sent only once and not resent on timeout? Is there an existing standard solution for this? Or is this because I have incorrectly configured some timeout value in Firefox config?

Comment: Under Options / Tabs there's an option "**Don't load tabs until selected**". Maybe this is causing an issue for you? Try unchecking it and see if it helps.

Comment: @Karan, no, like I said it's a problem only on intermittent connections. Normally I open multiple tabs in background without difficulty.